# Using gradients in HTML5 canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I need to to draw a non-rectangular
shape using lines. Then, add a vertical linear gradient to the shape with three color
stops.

I'm able to draw the shape but not getting the gradient.Can anyone help here?

This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

// Create gradient
var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
grd.addColorStop(0, "blue");
grd.addColorStop(1, "white");

// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle= grd;

ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,0);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(200,0);
ctx.lineTo(150,200);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(150,200);
ctx.lineTo(50,200);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.moveTo(50,200);
ctx.lineTo(0,0);
ctx.stroke();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You should set the strokeStyle, not the fillStyle:**

```
    ctx.strokeStyle= grd;
```

A typo(?) -- You have set 2 gradient stops at 0, so the red gradient will never display (just the blue an white will display).  For example, if you change the blue color stop to .5 then all 3 stops will display.

You might also thicken up the lineWidth a bit (that's a styling decision)

Also, you should begin a path with `ctx.beginPath` ( .lineTo commands are path commands ).

And .lineTo commands will continue from where the last .lineTo ended so you don't need all the .moveTo.

Your path drawing commands can become:

```
ctx.strokeStyle= grd;
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,0);
ctx.lineTo(150,200);
ctx.lineTo(50,200);
ctx.lineTo(0,0);
ctx.stroke();
```

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/sPdNu/

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Create gradient
    var grd=ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 0);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
    grd.addColorStop(0.5, "blue");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "white");

    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.strokeStyle= grd;
    ctx.lineWidth=5;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(200,0);
    ctx.lineTo(150,200);
    ctx.lineTo(50,200);
    ctx.lineTo(0,0);
    ctx.stroke();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi...thanks for pointing out the typo..I need to fill my shape with the linear gradient...so I set ctx.FillStyle= grd; It still doesnt work..

Comment: @Maksims Mihejevs: Please don't edit my answers in response to a questioners additional request.  In this case you have edited my answer into non-working code (`fillStyle` requires `fill` to be effective).  Instead, please post a comment and I'll be glad to add to my answer.  But I do appreciate the attempt--Thanks!

Comment: @user3373697 Just to clarify, you want the polygon to be gradient filled rather than gradient stroked--or both?  Here's a version with gradient fill:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7dY98/

Comment: @markE the person edited your answer was user3373697 and he had a mistake (used FillStyle instead of fillStyle) which I've corrected. Please in the future refer to [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22446466/revisions) area to check out who did and what edits. Thanks.

Comment: @markE as well there are no "rules" about who edits what in SO, as far as it has benefit to the community, just to clarify - as it looks like you trying to have "ownership" instead of "contribution" to the community information. :)

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs.  No, not at all-Sorry!  I just didn't want my previously working answer to be edited into something that no longer works.  User3373697 edited my code to FillStyle (his edited code would fail with an error).  You edited his edit to fillStyle (your edited code would run but would not be correct--ctx.fillStyle must be followed by ctx.fill() for the fill to be displayed).  Again, I appreciate your efforts!

Comment: I'm not saying that edits were valid, Review section is about "reviewing" edits, and mostly not about validating logic of the code, as people validate edits for common-sense in order to coop with volume of moderation work needs to be done. I just followed flow.
But if the code did not worked - indeed, user3373697 should not have edited your answer in first place.
Just I were mentioned and blamed very unfair due to lack of evidence regarding of who edited post. And it did sound like you are very "protective". Thanks.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs.  Please--No blame on you (or OP).  We both believe in edits.  I am only "protective" as far as having good code displayed with my name (no matter how the good code gets there).  Really--we're good!

Comment: @markE no problem at all! :) It is a good answer though, well detailed. I wish I had more time to StackOverflow..